# Positioning views inside Cooordinator Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout

I create the following view inside a Coordinator layout

```
<com.noodles.numbersgrame.MyRotated90ArrowClass
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/rotated90_arrow"
    android:textColor="@color/overlay_red_plusminus"
    android:elevation="15dp"

    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:rotation="-90"

    app:layout_anchor="@id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center_horizontal" />
```

**notice that I rotate the view -90 degrees.**

Here is the picture of the view:

[image]

*How can I make the arrow pointing up sit at the top of the hexagon? The hexagon has an id of my_image_view*

I have tried setting ***android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"  and also android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"***  but still the same problem.

I also tried ***app:layout_insetEdge="top"*** but still the same problem.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please add the expected result that you want, so I can understand your question clearly

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI Hello. I just want the yellow vertical rectangle sitting on top of the hexagon. thanks